# AuthenticateAsServer won't accept PEM format certificates

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

```
X509CertificateCollection certCollec = 
new X509CertificateCollection(new X509Certificate[1] { xcert});

X509CertificateCollection certCollecpfx = 
new X509CertificateCollection(new X509Certificate[1] { pfxCert });

SSLStream.AuthenticateAsClient(apsHost, certCollec, SslProtocols.Default, false);
```

certCollec contains a certificate in PEM Format

certCollecpfx contains a certificate in PFX Format

AuthenticateAsClient server only works with PFX Format even though the X509Certificate2 object for the pem and the pfx has exactly the same raw data.

Why is this? It keeps telling me A call to SSPI Failed: The data was badly formatted.

Why won't it accept pem format?

I then tried to export the pem format into pfx and it still didn't accept it - same error, even though I exported it to pfx.

```
byte[] pemCertBytes = pemCert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "620fpass");
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\test\MyCert.pfx", pemCertBytes);
```

Comment: If I remember well to convert a certificate with private key from one format to another you must load the certificate using the flag X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable.

Answer (score 0):

```
even though the X509Certificate2 object for the pem and the pfx has exactly the same raw data.
```

I think that is true only in cases when the pem certificate contains the actual certificate along with the private key. Moreover, it has specific headers namely `BEGIN-CERTIFICATE` and `END-CERTIFICATE` enclosing the actual contents. pfx or pkcs#12 certificates contain certificates and private keys which can optionally be encrypted using passwords. If you have ever imported a certificate to Windows Certificate Store, you may have noticed that it prompts you to enter a password while doing this, this is essentially used to encrypt the private key of the certificate.

```
I then tried to export the pem format into pfx and it still didn't accept it
```

I would suggest using [openssl](http://openssl.org/) for doing this. The general syntax is

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```